# Flutter Tabbar with ExpansionTile

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar

Currently I'm trying to build ExpansionTile with TabBar, I create separately for each ExpansionTile, but when I combine it with tabbar, the expansiontile doesn't work properly maybe just look at the gif for a better understanding xD, what I am trying to do make it fluent with tabbar , maybe I missing something?

Because the code is to long and i got `Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 39405.` so a few code i copy into Pastebin

[Without Tabbar](https://i.imgur.com/8fRGjku.gif)

```
https://i.imgur.com/8fRGjku.gif
```

[image]

[With Tabbar](https://i.imgur.com/gZ5f0X3.gif)

```
https://i.imgur.com/gZ5f0X3.gif
```

[image]

This is the Code for the **menuTwo**

```
https://pastebin.com/CcL6VRPS
```

**TabBar**

```
https://pastebin.com/aBiyh1RN
```

**ExpandedOne**

```
https://pastebin.com/GgxCZrf8
```

**ExpandedTwo**

```
class ExpandedTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandedTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExpandedTwoState createState() => _ExpandedTwoState();
}

class _ExpandedTwoState extends State<ExpandedTwo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _sizeScreen = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
    var _sizeHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Material(
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.black),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          title: Text(
            'Expanded Two',
            style: GoogleFonts.rubik(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14),
          ),
          leading: Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFEFFFFFF), width: 3),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Icon(Icons.unsubscribe_sharp)),
          ),
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(15)),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_sizeHeight / 65,
                        _sizeScreen.hp(2), 0, _sizeHeight / 97),
                    child: Text(
                      'Informasi',
                      style: GoogleFonts.nunitoSans(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                          fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    thickness: 2,
                    color: Color(0xFEF6F6F6),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(3)),
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Text('Header',style: GoogleFonts.nunitoSans(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                      color: Colors.black
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Data',),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(2),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text('Empty'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(5),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,
                        _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(0),0,
                        _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(16)),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("Button");
                      },
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                              RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40))),
                          padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                              EdgeInsets.all(0.0))),
                      child: Ink(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xFEFFDD00),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                              minWidth: 100.0, minHeight: 40.0),
                          // min sizes for Material buttons
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          child: Text("Complete the Data",
                              style: GoogleFonts.nunitoSans(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
          initiallyExpanded: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ExpandedThree**

```
class ExpandedThree extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandedThree({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExpandedThreeState createState() => _ExpandedThreeState();
}

class _ExpandedThreeState extends State<ExpandedThree> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _sizeScreen = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);
    var _sizeHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Material(
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.black),
        child: ExpansionTile(
          collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          title: Text(
            'Expanded Three',
            style: GoogleFonts.rubik(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 14),
          ),
          leading: Container(
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(color: Color(0xFEFFFFFF), width: 3),
            ),
            child: Center(
                child: Icon(Icons.home)),
          ),
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_sizeHeight / 65,
                            _sizeScreen.hp(2), 0, _sizeHeight / 97),
                        child: Text(
                          'Source Information 1',
                          style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12)),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Type Source',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 11),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                'Not Yet Filled',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12)),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Source Information',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 11),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                'Not Yet Filled',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12)),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Note',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 11),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                'Not Yet Filled',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(_sizeHeight / 65,
                            _sizeScreen.hp(2), 0, _sizeHeight / 97),
                        child: Text(
                          'Source Information 2',
                          style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12)),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Source Type',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 11),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                'Not Yet Filled',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12)),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Source Information Name',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 11),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                'Not Yet Filled',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12),
                              _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(12)),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Note',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 11),
                              ),
                              Spacer(),
                              Text(
                                'Not Yet Filled',
                                style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    fontSize: 11,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal),
                              )
                            ],
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(24),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                            _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(16),
                            _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(0),
                            _sizeScreen.sizeWidth(16),
                            _sizeScreen.sizeHeight(16)),
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print("Complete the Data");
                          },
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8))),
                              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
                                  EdgeInsets.all(0.0))),
                          child: Ink(
                            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                  minWidth: 100.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                              // min sizes for Material buttons
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text("Complete the Data",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.rubik(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],),
            )
          ],
          initiallyExpanded: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I Change height on Tabbar (   height: *MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*,
          child: TabBarView(children: [MenuOne(), MenuTwo()]), ) into fix Height for example 500 , that solve my problem, if I am using mediaquery * number that's make the function scroll doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Change height on Tabbar ( height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, child: TabBarView(children: [MenuOne(), MenuTwo()]), ) into fix Height for example 500
`( height: 500, child: TabBarView(children: [MenuOne(), MenuTwo()]), ),` that solve my problem, if I am using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * number` that's make the function scroll doesn't work
The alternative way , i have class for size for like

```
class Screen {
  late Size screenSize;

  Screen(this.screenSize);

  double sizeHeight(height) {
    double resultCalculation = screenSize.width / height;
    return screenSize.height / resultCalculation;
  }

  double sizeWidth(width) {
    double resultCalculation = screenSize.width / width;
    return screenSize.width / resultCalculation;
  }

  double wp(percentage) {
    return percentage / 100 * screenSize.width;
  }

  double hp(percentage) {
    return percentage / 100 * screenSize.height;
  }

  double getWidthPx(int pixels) {
    return (pixels / 3.61) / 100 * screenSize.width;
  }

  static bool isScreenLarge(double width, double pixel) {
    return width * pixel >= 1440;
  }

  static bool isScreenMedium(double width, double pixel) {
    return width * pixel < 1440 && width * pixel >= 1080;
  }

  static bool isScreenSmall(double width, double pixel) {
    return width * pixel <= 720;
  }
}
```

and i just need to call that for the height
`var _sizeScreen = Screen(MediaQuery.of(context).size);`
and do `height: _sizeScreen.hp(70)`